# Not able to connect over ssh with my pi

Tags: ssh

My only possibility to connect with my raspberry is over ssh. I have crated a file named 'ssh' on my card as described in this post

https://hackernoon.com/raspberry-pi-headless-install-462ccabd75d0

The post also tells me that the first credential i have to use are:

user: pi & password: raspberry, but when trying to connect with these credentials the raspberry says 'access denied'.

Can anyone tell my what I am missing?

Comment: Are you able to ping your pi?

Comment: What exactly is the command do you use to connect to the RasPi? What operating system are you using?

Comment: Im not sure how to ping on it. When typing in my IP in putty it opens a cli which says 'login as:' and then when typing in 'pi' it says 'py@192.168...'s password:' then nothing will be accepted as a password.

Comment: I am using Windows 7. I just type the ip adress into putty. And I use port 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple. Just make sure you install the moste recent version of raspbian stretch. Mine was an old version. 
Enjoy.